# The markup in the document following the root element must be well formed. Although there is just one root element

Tags: android, xml

Please somebody tell me why am I getting this error and what to do about it? 
My research has told me that This happens when we have more than one root elements. but i have only one, which is

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <TextView <!error>
        android:id="@+id/id_TextView1_MainActivity"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="@+string/Text_TextView1_MainActivity"/>

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/id_TextView2_MainActivity"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="15dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/id_TextView1_MainActivity"
        android:text="@+string/Text_TextView2_MainActivity"/>  

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/id_EditText1_MainActivity"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/id_TextView2_MainActivity"
        android:hint="@+string/Hint_EditText1_MainActivity" />

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/id_TextView3_MainActivity"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="15dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/id_EditText1_MainActivity"
        android:text="@+string/Text_TextView3_MainActivity"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/id_EditText2_MainActivity"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/id_TextView3_MainActivity"
        android:hint="@+string/Hint_EditText2_MainActivity" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are closing your root `layout` before the end `/>`. That should be open and it should be closed at the end of the file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >  // remove the / here

<TextView <!error>
    android:id="@+id/id_TextView1_MainActivity"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="@+string/Text_TextView1_MainActivity"/>

<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/id_TextView2_MainActivity"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="15dp"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/id_TextView1_MainActivity"
    android:text="@+string/Text_TextView2_MainActivity"/>  

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/id_EditText1_MainActivity"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/id_TextView2_MainActivity"
    android:hint="@+string/Hint_EditText1_MainActivity" />

<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/id_TextView3_MainActivity"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="15dp"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/id_EditText1_MainActivity"
    android:text="@+string/Text_TextView3_MainActivity"/>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/id_EditText2_MainActivity"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/id_TextView3_MainActivity"
    android:hint="@+string/Hint_EditText2_MainActivity" />
```